# Magento 1 - How to display static block based on dropdown selection of created attribute?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to display a static block based on the selection that has been made when adding a product in the magento backend.

So the situation is, I am adding the product and select a option from a dropdown attribute which has been created. The options are:

-Do not show table
-Show table 1
-Show table 2
and so on...

Static blocks have been created realated to the dropdown options:

-Static block table 1
-Static block table 2
and so on...

I am using the following code in the phtml file which I want to display it:

```
<?php if
($_product->getAttributeText('tableselect') == "Table 1"): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('table_1_block')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Its not working for me, what am i doing wrong here? Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work. I had to make sure it was in the product model. Below is the working code for me.

```
<?php
if ($this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('tableselect') == "Table 1") {
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('table_1_block')->toHtml();
}
?>
```